# R CMD check complains about unexpected files in man

Tags: emacs, r, software-distribution

this sounds like a silly problem: I'm putting my R code into a package and `R CMD check src` complains about the .Rd~ backup files being produced by Emacs.

```
* checking package subdirectories ... WARNING
Subdirectory 'man' contains invalid file names:
  read.PI.Rd~ write.PI.Rd~
```

the documentation says: »In addition [...] files [...]  with base names [...] ending in ‘~’, ‘.bak’ or ‘.swp’, are excluded by default.« (page 18).  but then why the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a file `cleanup` which removes them in your top-level directory. Also, you could build a tarball or zip archive first via `R CMD build` and the check this archive via `R CMD check` -- that should skip these filese as well.

Also, exactly how are you calling `R CMD check`, and what is your directory layout?  With R 2.10.0 on Linux, I just ran `touch pkg/man/foo.Rd~` for one of my packages, and `R CMD check pkg` (where `pkg` is the top-level directory as common for source projects stored on R-Forge)
did not issue this warning you are seeing.  The file was not removed by `cleanup` as that currently purges only in `src`.

Comment: first building the tar.gz and then checking it does avoid the warnings.  but then: the `cleanup` is not invoked during `R CMD check`, I also would not want to remove these backup files, I'd be happy with `check` ignoring them just as `build` already does.  you're telling me I don't have this option?

Comment: Not sure. Your best bet is probably to look at the source code of 'check' in $RHOME/bin. From a very casual look it does have some tests for '~'.  And as I said: this problem does not bite me, so I am not quite sure a) why it bites you and b) how you'd get around it. Hence my follow-up question.

Comment: I'm so sorry: I was calling it with `--check-subdirs=yes`.  removing that option removed the warnings.

Comment: No worries -- these things happen, and R has a gazillion subcommands.  Congrats on doing the right thing: organising your code as packages. It is definitely worth the effort.